# Using XML with XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

The question is quite silly, but I am completely stuck. I want to extract child nodes of a node based on a condition. The XML is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<products xmlns="http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/products">
    <product>
        <productID>1</productID>
        <picture>1000</picture>
        <productName>abc</productName>
        <price>400</price>
    </product>
    <product>
        <productID>2</productID>
        <picture>2000</picture>
        <productName>bcd</productName>
        <price>275</price>
    </product>
</products>
```

I want to use local-name() with contains.

My expression is: `//*[local-name()='products' and contains(productName,'a')]`

But not working.

Has anyone any idea of what I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to get the `product` tag, so this could help:

```
'//*[local-name()="products"]/*[local-name()="product" and contains(./*[local-name()="productName"], "a")]'
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use local-name() with contains.

This XPath,

```
//*[local-name()='productName' and contains(., 'a')]/..
```

uses `local-name()` and `contains()` to select all parent elements of those `productName` elements whose string value contains an `'a'`, as requested.